# What is wrong with this code asp.net using vb

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am getting this Error

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'user'.

```
    con.Open()
    comm.Connection = con
    comm.CommandText = "insert into user (username,firstname,lastname,email,password) values ('" & TextBox1.Text & "','" & TextBox2.Text & "','" & TextBox3.Text & "','" & TextBox4.Text & "','" & TextBox5.Text & "')"
    comm.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Response.Write("Data Successfully Saved")
```

Answer (score 3):

`User` is reserve key word, so use it like this

```
"insert into [user]
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use square brackets around `user` as it's a keyword.

By the way, this type of query is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. (Think about what you can put into your text boxes to drop the entire users table, or how you could convert the first few names and passwords into an e-mail address for the user you're inserting.) You should use parameterised queries instead or stored procedures.