# how can i try and catch duplicate data in the database

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

```
Try
            con.Open()
            comm.Connection = con
            comm.CommandText = "insert into [adminanduser] (username,firstname,lastname,email,password,usertype) values ('" & TextBox1.Text & "','" & TextBox2.Text & "','" & TextBox3.Text & "','" & TextBox4.Text & "','" & TextBox5.Text & "','" & Label6.Text & "')"
            comm.ExecuteNonQuery()
            Response.Write("Data Successfully Saved")
            con.Close()

        Catch
        Finally


        End Try
```

Comment: your code is wide open to SQL injection attacks as described in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35646276/1070452) to your question yesterday.  Try adding a user named `D'Artagnan` and you'll see another reason.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you alter the table such that there is a unqiue constraint on one of the columns, you will not be able to get an exception when inserting duplicate data. Rather than attempting to generate an error though, you could always use SQL to ensure that a duplicate entry won't be added. Presuming you are trying to keep unique usernames, you could always write your SQL like this:

```
comm.CommandText = @"IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM [adminanduser] WHERE [username] = @username)
                     INSERT INTO [adminanduser] SELECT @username,@firstname,@lastname,@email,@password,@usertype";
comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", TextBox1.Text);
comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@firstname", TextBox2.Text);
comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lastname", TextBox3.Text);
comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", TextBox4.Text);
comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", TextBox5.Text);
comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@usertype", TextBox6.Text);
```

If you would rather go down the road of generating the error, try

```
ALTER TABLE [adminanduser]
ADD UNIQUE (username)
```

That should throw an exception the next time you attempt to insert a duplicate username